# I lost the Copy & Paste Function in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: copy, paste

Noticed something a bit strange several weeks ago when I tried to Copy & Paste something off the desktop. I download items off the Internet to my desktop then use Copy & Paste into an appropriate file elsewhere. Somehow, I lose the paste function.

After a whole bunch of error, I did find a workaround by sending the file off the desktop to Trash. Once in Trash, I can Copy & Paste into whichever file I need to. What can I do to  have it function normally without sending it to Trash?

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to a malfunction of the Gnome Shell extension "Desktop Icons", which is providing the icons on the desktop. Formally, that would be provided by the file manager. Because support was dropped, an extension takes over that function. The extension, however, is quite limited.

You can manipulate files and folder on the desktop from within the file manager in the "Desktop" folder. Alternatively, you could try disabling the Desktop Extension, and instead install "Desktop Extension NG" from the Gnome Extensions website. That forked version that extension may give you a better experience. It has become the default extension in Ubuntu versions after 20.04.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you, I'll give that a try.

Comment: OK, installed Desktop Extension NG. Disabling Desktop Extension did nothing. The Desktop Extension NG doubled the icons on the desktop with same name and made the original ones inoperable and getting weird behavior.

Comment: Disabling Desktop Icons should disable desktop icons. If it didn't, then you did not disable the extension. You may need to uninstall it in 20.04: sudo remove gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons.

Comment: Entered command into terminal result was: sudo: remove: command not found

Comment: Should be "sudo apt remove ..." rather than "sudo remove..."

Comment: That appears to have done some good, thank you!  It's still a bit clunky as the C & P still doesn't work, but can drag and drop which I couldn't do before. Also the double icons have disappeared from the desktop.